# What is the overhead instrument panel (pictured) near the front galley area of an A320?

Tags: aircraft-systems, airbus-a320, feature-identification, cabin-design

I have noticed this overhead instrument panel. It is convered by a transparent plastic lid with a small hole in the middle. Inside it has lot of switches. What is it supposed to do and who operates the same?

I couldn't find an exact picture, but the below image highlights the area where the panel is:

[image]

[Image Source](https://www.gettyimages.in/detail/news-photo/cameraman-films-inside-the-airbus-a320-operated-by-avianca-news-photo/841560844)

Answer (score 7):

[image]
([easamodul10.blogspot.com](https://easamodul10.blogspot.com/2015/11/airbus-a320-series-electrical-system.html))

That panel you saw is the **forward cabin circuit breaker panel.** There is also an aft one.

It is used by maintenance personnel and cabin crew. For example if a toilet becomes inoperative, pulling the 'vacuum sys C/B' for 30 seconds might solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks. Is there an enlarged image where I can see the labels of the buttons.

Comment: @Firee - Here you go: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMntU.png :)

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know passenger reading lights are controlled from here. Also, it is quite high up, can cabin crew reach it easily? I never saw anyone operating those buttons.

Comment: The reading lights are controlled from the seats. That's the circuit breaker, it cuts the power supply to the reading lights -- sort of like the [home circuit breakers](https://www.google.com/search?q=home+circuit+breaker&tbm=isch).

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom - a cargo loading system, why not ask a [new question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)? it is interesting and more people will see it that way.

Comment: @ymb1 Nevermind, I was able to satisfy my curiosity with Google.